# MacOs - How to move a binary from .app and run it

Tags: macos, code-signing-entitlements, .app

We have a huge project.

Until today we didn't use an .app but now we must in order to use Endpoint security and other stuff.

Until today our binary sat in /opt/XYZ/binary.bin

Now because of the .app, looks like it will have to be /opt/XYZ/Cool.app/Content/MacOs/binary.bin

This change really breaks our code and will cause a massive code change.

If I extract the binary from the app and place it in /opt/XYZ/binary.bin and run it, the process is killed.

Is there a way to extract it from the app and run it from /opt/XYZ ? any tool, command, resource, etc' will be great.

Comment: What if you just make a symlink? `ln -s /opt/XYZ/Cool.app/Content/MacOS/binary.bin /opt/XYZ/binary.bin`

Comment: Unfortunately, symlink won't change the Current Working Directory of the process.

Comment: Why do you need to change the current working directory? macOS doesn't change CWD anyway. The binary itself can change CWD for itself. This actually makes no sense to me.